# How can i upload and read a text file with spring webflux?

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux

I need to upload a file and read the content, with spring mvc that is easy, but with spring webflux I have no idea how to deal with a FilePart and a Flux of DataBuffer

I'm expecting something like this return:

```
    @PostMapping("/upload")
    fun readFile(@RequestPart("file", required = true) file: Mono<FilePart>): Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> {
        return Mono.just("my text content")
                .map {
                    ResponseEntity.ok()
                            .body(it)
                }
    }
```

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/7d02ba0694b7b20f3af0ecb739851a008aff5b95/spring-webflux/src/test/java/org/springframework/web/reactive/result/method/annotation/MultipartIntegrationTests.java#L265

Comment: look into sending multipart bodys with rest and then read this https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-multipart

Answer (score 0):

I made it work using the following code:

```
    @PostMapping("/upload")
fun readFile(@RequestPart("file", required = true) file: Mono<FilePart>): Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> {

    return file.flatMap {
        it.content().map { dataBuffer ->
            IOUtils.inputStreamAsString(dataBuffer.asInputStream(), "UTF-8")
        }.toMono()
    }.map {
        ResponseEntity.ok()
                .body(it)
    }
}
```

Comment: @JesseNelson why?